# How do I set a UITextView as an inputAccessoryView and adjust height on rotate

Tags: ios, uitextview, autolayout, inputaccessoryview

I'm setting a UITextView as the accessory to another UITextView...

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{

    UITextView *myAccessory = 
       [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height / 3)];
    [myAccessory setDelegate:self];
    [self.textView setInputAccessoryView:myAccessory];
 }
```

However, I want the height of the inputAccessoryView to expand/contract when the user rotates the device and also want the top of the UITextView to hug the top of the screen.

I've tried programatically creating autolayout constraints for the top of the inputAccessoryView, but this is to no avail, since inputAccessoryView has no superview hierarchy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is your text view's accessory input view another text view? That's really strange.

Comment: I have a UITableView that contains several editable fields.  One of those editable fields is a UITextView.  When the user taps on this UITextView/UITableViewCell, I want to consume the entire area between keyboard and nav bar with an editable text area (this is where the 2nd uitextview comes in).  This is primarily to make my landscape users happy, while providing the largest editable area possible for them.  Since iOS 8 is providing the predictive text bar, my landscape users have even less room than before to edit text.

Comment: I figured the inputAccessoryView would be an easy cheat for this, since the bottom of it always hugs the keyboard.  Once I figure out how to get the top to hug the navbar, I'm good to go.

Comment: You see this in the Facebook app with the "Comment" feature.  They implement a multi-line UITextView in the inputAccessoryView for comments.  I believe Snapchat does something similar as well.

Comment: I would check out how these guys do it: https://github.com/datwelk/RDRStickyKeyboardView

Comment: That RDRStickyKeyboardView is terrible